# Inserting in a table without primary key using Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, insert, primary-key

I can't find how to insert a row that doesn't have a PK. This isn't possible with a class that is extending Zend_Db_Table_Abstract, so how should I do this?

The table I in which I want to insert records is a join table.
The only two columns in it could serve as a PK, but I don't know how I should let Zend know that neither.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zend doesn't really care if the table have in fact a PK (or an index) or not. The `primary_key` option in a `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` is really just to know which column the 'WHERE' clause will search for when using `find` and `find*` methods, etc. So, basically, just specify which columns to use as reference columns for your *db model*. I can't give you more details since I don't know the details of the said table.

Comment: I see, I thought it did care for the PK to be in the table. ty